# setIdleTimerDisabled doesn't work

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, user-interface

I am using custom screen time out. Instead of `45Secs` I am changing the screen dimming time to `1 min`. For that I have sub classed `UIWindow` and monitored events by overriding `sendEvent` method.

To lock the screen while using `setIdleTimerDisabled` after time threshold reaches.

The screen doesn't lock.

Comment: do not test it in debug mode, try it on device after disconnecting from xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Do not test it in debug mode(debugger attached), try it on a device after disconnecting from xcode.